# Failed to emerge net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1

Tags: samba, gentoo, emerge, portage

I'm trying to update Gentoo to unstable. I executed `emerge @preserved-rebuild` because virtualbox-guest-additions install fails. `emerge @preserved-rebuild` stopped and threw error while Samba compiling.

`emerge @preserved-rebuild` error:

```
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #11): 
        {task: manpages/smb.conf.5 smb.conf.5.xml,parameters.all.xml -> smb.conf.5}
 * ERROR: net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   build failed
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  124:  Called src_compile
 *   environment, line 4542:  Called multilib-minimal_src_compile
 *   environment, line 2842:  Called multilib_foreach_abi 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 3073:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 2708:  Called _multibuild_run '_multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 2706:  Called _multilib_multibuild_wrapper 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line  495:  Called multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile
 *   environment, line 2836:  Called multilib_src_compile
 *   environment, line 3285:  Called waf-utils_src_compile
 *   environment, line 5566:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       "${WAF_BINARY}" ${_mywafconfig} ${jobs} || die "build failed"
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/log/portage/build/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1:20171015-174835.log'.
 * For convenience, a symlink to the build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/work/samba-4.7.0-abi_x86_32.x86'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/work/samba-4.7.0'

>>> Failed to emerge net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1, Log file:

>>>  '/var/log/portage/build/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1:20171015-174835.log'

 * Messages for package net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1:
 * Log file: /var/log/portage/build/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1:20171015-174835.log

 * ERROR: net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   build failed
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  124:  Called src_compile
 *   environment, line 4542:  Called multilib-minimal_src_compile
 *   environment, line 2842:  Called multilib_foreach_abi 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 3073:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 2708:  Called _multibuild_run '_multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line 2706:  Called _multilib_multibuild_wrapper 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
 *   environment, line  495:  Called multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile
 *   environment, line 2836:  Called multilib_src_compile
 *   environment, line 3285:  Called waf-utils_src_compile
 *   environment, line 5566:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       "${WAF_BINARY}" ${_mywafconfig} ${jobs} || die "build failed"
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/log/portage/build/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1:20171015-174835.log'.
 * For convenience, a symlink to the build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/work/samba-4.7.0-abi_x86_32.x86'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1/work/samba-4.7.0'
```

The result of emerge --info '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo':

```
Portage 2.3.11 (python 3.4.6-final-0, default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop, gcc-5.4.0, glibc-2.25-r7, 4.12.12-gentoo x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-4.12.12-gentoo-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i5-6300HQ_CPU_@_2.30GHz-with-gentoo-2.4.1
KiB Mem:     8037396 total,   3940796 free
KiB Swap:   12582908 total,  12389116 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Sun, 15 Oct 2017 10:00:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: 207d64181ea82d5d3251db27d856244b0e78ef6f
sh bash 4.4_p12
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.28.1 p1.0) 2.28.1
app-shells/bash:          4.4_p12::gentoo
dev-java/java-config:     2.2.0-r3::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:            5.24.3::gentoo
dev-lang/python:          2.7.14::gentoo, 3.4.6::gentoo
dev-util/cmake:           3.7.2::gentoo
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.28-r2::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.4.1-r2::gentoo
sys-apps/openrc:          0.32.1::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.10-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.13::gentoo, 2.69::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:       1.11.6-r1::gentoo, 1.15-r2::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:       2.28.1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:            5.4.0-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.8-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.6-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/make:           4.2.1::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 4.13::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.25-r7::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /usr/portage
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 

dotnet
    location: /var/lib/layman/dotnet
    sync-type: laymansync
    sync-uri: https://anongit.gentoo.org/git/proj/dotnet.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50

fw-overlay
    location: /var/lib/layman/fw-overlay
    sync-type: laymansync
    sync-uri: https://github.com/no-hope/fw-overlay.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50

seeds
    location: /var/lib/layman/seeds
    sync-type: laymansync
    sync-uri: git://github.com/vonavi/seeds.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64 ~amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/dconf /etc/env.d /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/php/apache2-php7.0/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php7.0/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php7.0/ext-active/ /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo /etc/texmf/language.dat.d /etc/texmf/language.def.d /etc/texmf/updmap.d /etc/texmf/web2c /usr/bin/startx"
CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs clean-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync multilib-strict news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms split-log strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync webrsync-gpg xattr"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="rsync://gentoo.prz.rzeszow.pl/gentoo"
LANG="en_GB.utf8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
USE="X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 berkdb bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cjk cli colord consolekit cracklib crypt cups curl custom-cflags cxx dbus dri dts dvd dvdr eds emboss encode evo exif fam firefox flac fontconfig fortran gdbm gif glamor gphoto2 gpm gsm gstreamer gtk hardened iconv introspection ipv6 jack java jpeg kerberos lcms ldap libnotify libsecret lzma mad mng modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib nautilus ncurses nls nptl odbc ogg openal opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf perl png policykit postgres ppds python qt3support qt4 readline savedconfig scanner sdl seccomp session socks5 spell ssl startup-notification svg tcl tcpd threads tiff tools tracker truetype udev udisks unicode upower usb userlocales v4l vaapi vim-syntax vorbis wifi wxwidgets x264 xattr xcb xcomposite xinerama xml xv xvid zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump author" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput synaptics evdev mouse keyboard" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" NGINX_MODULES_HTTP="fastcgi access addition auth_basic auth_ldap auth_pam auth_request autoindex browser cache_purge charset dav dav_ext degradation echo empty_gif fancyindex flv geo geoip gunzip gzip gzip_static headers_more image_filter limit_conn limit_req lua map memc memcached metrics mp4 naxsi perl proxy push_stream random_index realip referer rewrite scgi secure_link security slice slowfs_cache spdy split_clients ssi sticky stub_status sub upload_progress upstream_check upstream_hash upstream_ip_hash upstream_keepalive upstream_least_conn upstream_zone userid uwsgi xslt" NGINX_MODULES_MAIL="imap pop3 smtp" NGINX_MODULES_STREAM="access geo geoip limit_conn map realip return split_clients ssl_preread upstream_hash upstream_least_conn upstream_zone" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-6" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres9_5" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_4" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby22" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="nvidia" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CC, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

The result of emerge -pqv '=net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1::gentoo':

```
[ebuild     U ] net-fs/samba-4.7.0-r1 [4.5.10-r1] USE="acl cups fam ldap pam python%* system-mitkrb5 winbind -addc -addns -ads -client -cluster -debug% -dmapi -gnutls -gpg -iprint -quota (-selinux) -syslog (-system-heimdal) -systemd {-test} -zeroconf" ABI_X86="32 (64) (-x32)" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 

 * IMPORTANT: 7 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.
```

Build log: https://filebin.ca/3dtv8kEB1Wjp/samba-4.7.0-r120171015-174835.log.txt

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that "WAF" error in samba, but I have seen it in samba dependency packages.  It's solved with them by MAKEOPTS="-j1" and no distcc, it doesn't appear you are using distcc, but I do and samba fails with it, had to disable for samba.  But I didn't have to fool with makeopts, left at -j3 here (on x86_64).
I find it utterly amazing that distcc is put out by the Samba devs, yet it (& friends) cannot use it.
Anyhow, I suggest trying -j1.